# wildfly-9.0.0.Final stops automatically on linux x86. fedora 3.14.8-200.fc20. java version "1.8.0_45". How can i fix it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, java-8, wildfly

wildfly-9.0.0.Final stops working on linux machine. 
I have no idea why. please help.

**Server Log:**

[CodeBlob (0xa752af48)]

Framesize: 0

BufferBlob (0xa752af48) used for StubRoutines (2)

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:834), pid=2211, tid=482995008
  fatal error: exception happened outside interpreter, nmethods and vtable stubs at pc 0xa752c8d4

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/bin/hs_err_pid2211.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

./standalone.sh: line 346:  2211 Aborted                 "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" -D"[Standalone]" -server -server -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" -jar "/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar" -mp "/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir="/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final" -Djboss.server.base.dir="/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone"

**standalone.conf:**

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"

else

echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"

fi
```

Comment: The `/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/bin/hs_err_pid2211.log` should have more details, but it looks like something in the JVM. Is there anything unique about your environment?

Comment: i have linux x86 machine, i think nothing unique. 
please see the log:
https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12390932/hs_err_pid2211.log

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your JVM crashed. As a general rule, the JVM should never crash. It might crash, though, under some circumstances:

- A bug in the JVM
- A bug in some software that the JVM relies upon (rare, as the JVM is made to deal with most of those cases)
- Some hardware failure (bad memory, for instance)

To find what's wrong, try to answer the following questions:

- Is this happening in other machines as well? If so, chances are that it's not a hardware problem.
- Is it happening with other VMs? It seems you are using Oracle's JVM, so, you might want to try on OpenJDK that ships with Fedora.
- Is it happening also with the newest Fedora? It seems you are running Fedora 20, which is two versions behind the most recent.
- Which component is causing the failure? I see that you have a lot of components running, such as Spring, Mongo, Zookeeper, Solr, ... Try to strip out some code and remove a dependency at a time, to determine which one is triggering the problem. Once you find it, do the opposite: start from a blank state, adding only this dependency and your code, adding a piece at a time, to see what exactly is triggering the problem. Once you find it, it will be easier for the developers of the component to reproduce the issue and fix it.

Although I cannot tell you how to fix the problem, you might find the solution once you diagnose what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/application-crashes-due-to-internal-error-sharedruntime-cpp-833-caused-by-java-8-bug-740098867.html) are more details on this particular issue and solution.

> ## Cause
>
> This happens due to a bug in OpenJDK (JDK-8067755 and JDK-8068663) and
> is triggered by terminating SSL at Tomcat.
>
> ## Workaround
>
> #### Option #1
>
> Add the -XX:-UseAESIntrinsics flag to the JVM.   BITBUCKET SERVER
> JIRA   CONFLUENCE The flag provided in the workaround above should
> work however, the original Tomcat thread suggests adding the parameter
> below instead:
>
> 1
> -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/sun/crypto/provider/*.* We've had customers succeed by adding the UseAESIntrinsics parameter so only use
> this option if that one doesn't work.
>
> #### Option #2
>
> Add a proxy in front of the application to terminate SSL before
> Tomcat.  More information about this can be found here:   Proxying and
> securing Bitbucket Server. Integrating JIRA with Apache Configuring
> Web Proxy Support for Confluence
>
> ## Resolution
>
> We have confirmed that Java 8u60 contains the fix. Upgrade to Java
> 8u60 or later.